# How to print a hollow square?

Tags: c++, console-application

I used a two dimensional for loop to make a shape producing function for a class assignment but I couldn't get it to make a hollow square; only a filled one. I pass in two arguments the width and the symbol being used.

I've played around with it several times but I eventually just turned it in with one incompletion.
It should print something like this

```
++++
+  +
+  +
++++
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shapemaker.h"

using namespace std;

void shapemaker::Initialize(int w, int h, char sym)
{
  width = w;
  height = h;
  symbol = sym;
}

int shapemaker::getcanWidth() {return width;}

int shapemaker::getcanHeight() {return height;}

char shapemaker::getSymbol() {return symbol;}

void shapemaker::setSymbol(char s) { symbol = s; }

void shapemaker::setcanWidth(int w) { width = w; }

void shapemaker::setcanHeight(int h) { height = h; }

void shapemaker::drawmidHorline()
{
  symbol = getSymbol();
  int drawingheight = getcanHeight();
  int drawingwidth = getcanWidth();
  double midpoint = getcanHeight()/2;
  for(int x = 0; x < drawingwidth; x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < drawingwidth; y++)
    {
      if(x == midpoint)
      cout << getSymbol();
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void shapemaker::drawmidVertline()
{
  symbol = getSymbol();
  int drawingheight = getcanHeight();
  int drawingwidth = getcanWidth();
  double midpoint = getcanWidth()/2;

  for(int x = 0; x < drawingwidth;x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < drawingheight; y++)
    {
      if(y == midpoint)
      {
        cout << getSymbol();
      }
      cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void shapemaker::drawWidthsizedFullSquare()
{
  symbol = getSymbol();
  int drawingwidth = getcanWidth();
  for(int x = 0; x < drawingwidth;x++)
  {
    cout << symbol;
    for(int y = 0; y < drawingwidth; y++)
    {
      cout << symbol;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void shapemaker::drawWidthsizedOpenSquare()
{
  symbol = getSymbol();
  int drawingwidth = getcanWidth();
  for(int x = 0; x < drawingwidth;x++)
  {
    cout << getSymbol();
    for(int y = 0; y < drawingwidth; y++)
    {
      if(x == 0 || x == drawingwidth-1)
      cout << getSymbol();
    }
    cout << getSymbol();
    cout << endl;       
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the pattern you want to output.

Comment: I think you've added the pattern, but it doesn't print correctly. Consider using a code block to get the pattern to print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `drawWidthsizedOpenSquare` to print this

```
++++
+  +
+  +
++++
```

you should write this method like:

```cpp
void shapemaker::drawWidthsizedOpenSquare()
{
  symbol = getSymbol();
  int drawingwidth = getcanWidth();
  for(int x = 0; x < drawingwidth;x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < drawingwidth; y++)
    {
      if(x == 0 || x == drawingwidth-1 || y == 0 || y == drawingwidth-1)  // border cell case
      {
        cout << getSymbol();
      }
      else
      {
        cout << " ";
      }
    }
    cout << endl;       
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect appreciate the perspective.

Comment: You could remove the checking for the border cases and instead, print the borders before and after the `y` loop.